# How does the dash home index work in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, launcher, unity-dash

I think the Dash Home is really cool and here's something I wanna learn about:

When I type `shortcut`, it can prompt `keyboard` like this [snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siUyf.png).

I wanna know how Ubuntu determines `shortcut` is related to `keyboard`? 
What if I want to get `Chrome` when I type `www`?

Comment: Sorry, can you tell us exactly what you are wanting to do? The question is a little vague and needs padding out a bit.

Comment: @SimplySimon just edited it, hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it just indexes the keywords defined on each application launcher.

In your case, the launcher from "Keyboard" is stored in `/usr/share/applications/gnome-keyboard-panel.desktop` and has the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Keyboard
Comment=Change keyboard settings
Exec=gnome-control-center keyboard
Icon=preferences-desktop-keyboard
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Settings;HardwareSettings;X-GNOME-Settings-Panel;
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Bugzilla=GNOME
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Product=gnome-control-center
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Component=keyboard
X-GNOME-Bugzilla-Version=3.6.3
X-GNOME-Settings-Panel=keyboard
# Translators: those are keywords for the keyboard control-center panel
Keywords=Shortcut;Repeat;Blink;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=gnome-control-center-2.0
```

If you try each one of the keywords defined there, "Keyboard" is shown as an option in the launcher.

So, if you want to make dash to show Chromium when you type "WWW", just add a `Keywords` stanza in `/usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop`:

```
(Content omitted)
StartupNotify=true
Actions=NewWindow;Incognito;TempProfile;
X-AppInstall-Package=chromium-browser
Keywords=WWW;
(...)
```

Also, please note that this file probably will be overwritten when Chromium is updated, so probably it would be better to copy the edit file to `~/.local/share/applications/`.

Comment: Cool! Now I'm clear about *.desktop file and thanks for reminds of the overwritten things